# Before/After Difference for a flexible Date (Case)

Tags: sql, case, sql-date-functions

i have a little problem with a case.  I output two date fields (yyyy-mm-dd).  the date changes and is flexible.  not every entry has the same date fields.

I take one date field as an fixed point. If the Date is 4 months before the date, a 'V' should be the output. if it is behind it, an 'N' should be the output.

```
SELECT
a.FIELD1,
b.FIELD2,
c.FIELD3,
d.DATE1, -- YYYY-MM-DD
e.DATE2 -- YYYY-MM-DD
CASE
    WHEN e.DATE2 >= d.DATE1 THEN = 'N'
    WHEN e.DATE2 < d.DATE1 THEN = 'V' -- >= 4 MONTHS BEFORE
END AS DATE_SIGN
```

I heard that are problems with the date format i get. The Datediff works only with another format, right?

Can I use the two Dates in a Case like this?

Kind regards

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking - is there a problem with your results? Presumably your date columns are the correct `date` data type? `Date` data types are not any particular *format* and you can compare dates exactly as you have done. What happens if the two dates are equal?

Comment: Thanks, yes the date fields have the same Data Types. I edit the question if the data fields are qual.

Comment: The risk of comparing dates comes mostly from comparing datetimes. F.e.  `'2021-01-01' <= '2021-01-01'` is true but `'2021-01-01 00:00:01' <= '2021-01-01'` is false

Comment: Indeed. Thanks God the dates are the same type and only YYYY-MM-DD without time. How i write the case `>= 4 Months before the Date` ???

Comment: *the date fields have the same Data Types* that may be, but what *is* the type.

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD` is the type

Comment: You're using the word "type" where I believe you mean "format".

Comment: Yes sry, format is `YYYY-MM-DD` and type is `Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephan, I'm not sure if I understand this correctly but I think you are asking how you can check if DATE2 is more than 4 months earlier than DATE1?

If so you could use the DATEADD function in SQL Server, it would be something like

WHEN DATE2 < DATEADD(MONTH, -4, DATE1) THEN 'V'

In MySQL the DATE_ADD function is similar but would be

WHEN DATE2 < DATE_ADD(DATE1, INTERVAL -4 MONTH) THEN 'V'